# Random image generator

Tags: swift

Im trying to display a random image after the push of a button. I have named the 4 images "gameBall1, gameBall2, gameBall3 and gameBall4" and made outlets for them

Here is my attempt:

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "gameBall(arc4random_uniform(3) + 1).png")
}
```

I get an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier "ImageView""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems.

If it says undefined identifier ImageView then it means that you don't have a variable ImageView that is tied to your UIImageView. You need to fix that.

(Open your view controller's scene in the Storyboard. Open the assistant editor and display the view controller's source code. Control-drag from the image view in interface builder into the body of your view controller to define an outlet.)

(You should name variables beginning with lower case letters btw.)

Your code to set the image name is also wrong. You should create a temporary variable with the name of the image in it and display it with a `println` statement to check it. You are missing a backslash around the `(arc4random_uniform(3) + 1)` part. It should read

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "gameBall\(arc4random_uniform(3) + 1).png")
```

Comment: Really new to this, so i'm very grateful for all these helpful responses!

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if your IBOutlet is set up correctly to your UIImageView.

Then you can try it like this:

**EDIT:**
In order to get random number between 1 and 4 you should use `arc4random_uniform(4) + 1` :

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
    ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "gameBall\(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1).png")
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put the images in an image view where I want to display them?

Comment: No, you are loading them dynamically by setting your `UIImageView`'s image property.